# Angular 8 setErrors set a control as invalid but doesn't update on template

Tags: angular, angular8

I have the following code on my component

```
   this.frmGroup.controls['dorms'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

then in my template I have this to debug:

```
   {{this.frmGroup.controls['dorms'].invalid  }}
```

After setting erros the invalid property of the dorms control is always false on the template

if I execute this:

this.frmGroup.controls['dorms'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
console.log(this.frmGroup.controls['dorms'].invalid) // it is true but the template doesn't change it is as false

Answer (score 1):

You may have to run `this.frmGroup.get('dorms').updateValueAndValidity();` to get the changes recognized by your template.

Answer (score 0):

Like iamword said or also this.frmGroup = ...this.frmGroup